# vba string max size

Tags: vba, excel

is there a limit in vba string variable?

```
Public query As String
query="select * from ......"
```

i type a query that's very long and at a certain point it just stop, i can't type anything more in the quotes
i tried to copy paste my query from notepad but the query is being split to new line

i tried to print the length it's stop at 1005

```
len(query)
```

if there really is a limit in vba string
how should i do a very long string then?

Comment: The maximum length of a string in VBA is ~2 *billion* characters, the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem when writing queries as well.  The way around it I found was as follows :-

```
query = "SELECT * " & _
        "FROM...."
```

Then when you reach a suitable juncture :-

```
query = query & "WHERE...."
```

etc.  I believe the maximum is in inputting to the string in one go, not on the actual overall length.  This solution got me around the problem, so hopefully will aid you.

Comment: hmmm doesn't work for me, when i msgbox the length it's 1091 (doesn't really different) and the debug info is still the same

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177324.aspx) :

> The zero length empty string and all possible character sequences
>   using characters from the implementation dependent character set.
>   There MAY be an implementation defined limit to the length of such
>   sequences but the limit SHOULD be no smaller than (2^16 – 1)
>   characters.

So you should be able to have a string length of at least 65535 characters.
However, the editor seems to have some kind of restriction regarding the length of line code, not just strings.
As mentionned, use `_` to split a line code.

Comment: the underscore doesn't work for me, or is there any limitation in query when using mysql odbc 3.5.1 driver?

Comment: @user3725273 Any error message? You need to split so you can have enough space for the `&` and underscore. Also `"` needs to be closed and reopened on the next line. Plus you need be a space before the `_`. Example: `query = "select * from table1234" & _` `" where ..."` Also don't forget the space needed inside the string.